# Ionic/vue component import works but give an "Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations"

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, vuejs3, vite, vitest

I am importing a vue component in a unit test. i can work with it but it gives the following error:
Vue: Cannot find module  @/views/DetectorPage.vue  or its corresponding type declarations.

[error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYKqv.png)

I am writing in Ionic with vue3 and composition api and typescript.

Please ask for extra info if needed because this is my first post so i don't know what info i need to give.

I removed the vue extention but it gives the same error. The same errors occurs when importing in another component.

removing the @ and using ../ also gives the same error.

[error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXFML.png)

this is my tsconfig.json file

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

and this is my vite.config.js file

```
import legacy from "@vitejs/plugin-legacy";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), legacy()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
    coverage: {
      provider: "v8",
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.